# discordbot.pyで天気を表示するbotを作っていたところエラーが出ました: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'

Tags: python, discord

Python3.7を使ってます。
初プログラミングなのと、初質問なんで、わかりにくいところがあるかもしれません。
よければどんどん指定してください。

**ソースコード**

```
# coding: UTF-8
import discord
import urllib.request
import jso
import re

client = discord.Client()

citycodes = {
    "土浦": '080020',
    "水戸": '080010',
    "札幌": '016010',
    "仙台": '040010',
    "東京": '130010',
    "横浜": '140010',
    "名古屋": '230010',
    "大阪": '270000',
    "広島": '340010',
    "福岡": '400010',
    "鹿児島": '460010',
    "那覇": '471010'
}

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("logged in as " + client.user.name)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author != client.user:

    reg_res = re.compile(u"Bot君、(.+)の天気は？").search(message.content)
    if reg_res:

      if reg_res.group(1) in citycodes.keys():

        citycode = citycodes[reg_res.group(1)]
        resp = urllib.request.urlopen('http://weather.livedoor.com/forecast/webservice/json/v1?city=%s'%citycode).read()
        resp = json.loads(resp.decode('utf-8'))

        msg = resp['location']['city']
        msg += "の天気は、\n"
        for f in resp['forecasts']:
          msg += f['dateLabel'] + "が" + f['telop'] + "\n"
        msg += "です。"

        await client.send_message(message.channel, message.author.mention + msg)

      else:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "そこの天気はわかりません...")

client.run("TOKEN")
```

**表示されたエラー**

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/DiscordBOT/TenkiBOT/discordbot.py", line 47, in on_message
    await client.send_message(message.channel, message.author.mention + msg)
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

Comment: `send_message` メソッドは `discord.Client.http` クラスにありますので、`client.http.send_message(...)` とするのではないでしょうか。

Comment: [クイックスタート](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/quickstart.html)だと`message.channel.send()`を使っているようですが。

Comment: @Aruhu まず、お使いのライブラリは discordbot.py ではなく discord.py ではないでしょうか（ご自身のファイル名と混同されていませんか？）　また、discord.py はバージョンによって結構使い方が違うので、discord.py のバージョン情報を教えて欲しいです。

Comment: もう少し詳しく解説した記事がこれらでしょう。[Pythonで実用Discord Bot(discordpy解説)](https://qiita.com/1ntegrale9/items/9d570ef8175cf178468f), [Discord Bot を 簡単・手軽 に 動かす](https://note.com/grarich/n/n0680db0c0324), [How to Make a Discord Bot in Python](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/)

Answer (score 0):

47行目を
`await message.channel.send(messange.author.mention + msg)`
50行目を
`await message.channel.send("そこの天気はわかりません...")`
にしてみてください。それでも使えない場合は、
`from discord.ext import commands` をして、
`bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')`を入れて、5
50行目の後に
`await bot.process_commands(message)`を入れてください。